# How to handle password storage for my project?

Tags: passwords, virtualization, python

We have NFC cards to keep track of presence, students scan their card to a terminal at the beginning of every lesson, we want to extend the cards usage to filter out who can access the Raspberry Pi's inside the building without adding much of a hassle.

These Pi's are thin-clients, so authentication to a VM will need to be done as well.

Now for the basic of unlocking the pi itself, I'm going to rely on xlock.

We launch the program on Pi's startup then this will start xlock. The program will start checking if a NFC Tag is read, and if so what's the ID of the tag?
So, now got the ID of the tag, let's check in the database if the owner of the tag has permission to use the Pi. Let's assume he does have permission, kill [xlock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xlock), go to the database and check the password belonging to the users VM, and log him in through rdesktop.

The specific threat I want to adress: How can I prevent someone to use someone elses VM (By hacking the database and retrieving plaintext passwords for example).

Options I have thought of:
If a user wants access, write something on his tag.

I think I found a solution:
Authentication user account handles authentication, [then opens rdesktop](https://superuser.com/questions/603604/ubuntu-x11-is-it-possible-to-open-an-x-application-in-another-users-session) on the "student" account, the student will not be able to read through the code and figure out how to get into the database. And as a bonus on security, only allow the students to use port 80 and TCP port 3389 and UDP port 3389.

Comment: It would be very interesting to know the original problem you are solving. This might help us come up with superior designs.

Comment: @TomNewton We have NFC cards to keep track of presence, the  students scan their card to a terminal at the beginning of every lesson, we want to extend the cards usage to filter out who can access the Raspberry Pi's inn the building without adding much of a hassle, that's why I choose to use those cards. The cards are read-able by NFC but a regular cloning app on a smartphone will say "Can't clone low-level card", so cloning isn't really simple for the students.

Answer (score -2):

Relying on NFC for authentication makes your project's security flawed by design.

NFC cards alone doesn't provide a secure way to avoid eavesdropping and replay attacks. NFC cards can be easily read/write from wider distances than expected.

For the VM authentication, I would advice not to store passwords either. 
Explore other authentication means, such as smart cards.

Have a look at http://www.nearfieldcommunication.org/nfc-security.html for more on NFC (in)security.

Comment: The VM is only accesible from the building itself, the MySQL data is only accesible from the building aswell, so there isn't a huge security threat. I know it isn't a failsafe way, but it'll prevent 99% of the users hacking others. (Further than that who the hell would steal students code? Except for students).


The only real security threat are the IT'ers (in education) that want to break into the database to troll other users with this, the NFC tag can be replicated, but can also be disabled, and exchanged for a new one with another ID. So that is not a huge threat.

Comment: For further info: The tags we use are MIFARE DESFire EV1's.

Comment: It's a shame that I've got downvoted.
NFC insecurities such as spoofing is of widespread knowledge.
See [Cloning Cryptographic RFID Cards for 25$ ?](http://www.proxmark.org/files/Documents/13.56%20MHz%20-%20MIFARE%20DESFire/Cloning_Cryptographic_RFID_Cards_for_25USD-WISSEC_2010.pdf).
Cloning is not necessary when you can spoof. A regular clonning app is not deterministic on NFC security.

Despite that my answer was down-voted, is sustain that your design is flawed in terms of security.

Comment: I know they are, but in THIS use case, we're talking about a school here, no-one in this school is going to spend 25$ on a card that will be useless once discovered, we're not talking about building security here, we're talking about a pi that needs unlocking in a monitored and isolated network. 

They would first have to steal someone elses card, then buy the device, clone it and magically make the card re-appear, and once discovered we just shut down the VM, de-activate the card and it's done. And the fact that they will get suspended, isn't very motivating for them either.